# Attempting Craft 2 -> 3 Upgrade | An Error occurred while handling another error

Tags: craft3, updating

I'm trying to upgrade Craft 2 -> 3.

I can install Craft 3 no problem, but when I try starting over/upgrading I'm hitting this error.

The Craft 2 site is running the latest version of Craft.

MacOS High Sierra

MAMP Pro 5.0.4

[image: Abort, Try again, Continue Anyway]

When I continue anyway I get this error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:

Stack trace:
yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid path alias: @baseUrl/ in /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:154
#0 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(1080): yii\BaseYii::getAlias('@baseUrl/')
#1 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(167): craft\web\Request->_requestedSite(Object(craft\services\Sites))
#2 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Request->init()
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#4 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#5 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#6 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#7 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.web.php(13): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#8 [internal function]: {closure}()
#9 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(351): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#11 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#12 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request', true)
#13 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(333): yii\base\Module->get('request', true)
#14 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(74): craft\web\Application->get('request')
#15 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(499): yii\di\ServiceLocator->__get('request')
#16 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(115): yii\web\ErrorHandler->shouldRenderSimpleHtml()
#17 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(132): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\InvalidArgumentException))
#18 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): craft\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\InvalidArgumentException))
#19 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(63): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\InvalidArgumentException))
#20 [internal function]: craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\InvalidArgumentException))
#21 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid path alias: @baseUrl/ in /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:154
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(1080): yii\BaseYii::getAlias('@baseUrl/')
#1 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(167): craft\web\Request->_requestedSite(Object(craft\services\Sites))
#2 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Request->init()
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#4 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#5 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#6 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#7 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.web.php(13): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#8 [internal function]: {closure}()
#9 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(351): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#11 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#12 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request', true)
#13 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(333): yii\base\Module->get('request', true)
#14 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(160): craft\web\Application->get('request')
#15 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/App.php(371): yii\web\Application->getRequest()
#16 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.php(214): craft\helpers\App::logConfig()
#17 [internal function]: {closure}()
#18 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#19 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(351): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#20 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#21 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('log', true)
#22 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(333): yii\base\Module->get('log', true)
#23 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(508): craft\web\Application->get('log')
#24 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1133): yii\base\Application->getLog()
#25 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(106): craft\web\Application->_preInit()
#26 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Application->init()
#27 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#28 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(97): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#29 [internal function]: craft\web\Application->__construct(Array)
#30 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#31 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#32 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#33 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(252): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#34 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php(42): require('/Users/charlie....')
#35 /Users/charlie.triplett/Documents/Work/simple/Craft-3.0.26.1/web/index.php(20): require('/Users/charlie....')
#36 {main}
```

Comment: It looks like there is problem with alias settings. Look at config files in Craft 2 and 3 and find alias baseUrl. Is there any?

Comment: @lenka Yes one for my local and one for prod in my general.php config.

Comment: @lenka And… Ohhhhhh… I've got this figured out. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy that you've solve it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into the same error, my Craft 2 site had 3 environment settings:

Dev, Staging and Production.

This page covers how to carry those settings into Craft 3
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/environments.html

Thanks to @lenka for pointing me in the right direction!